# Integration of an application with keycloak for SSO using open id connect

Tags: c#, keycloak, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an application which developed few years back using .netcore 3.1. Now want to implement the SSO using keycloak with open id connect. Currently, when I run the app it can direct to keycloak sign in. But when successfully signed in, it can direct to application page but with error. Below is my setup:

Startup.cs

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireClaim("user_roles", "admin"));
                options.AddPolicy("Contractor", policy => policy.RequireClaim("user_roles", "contractor"));
                options.AddPolicy("Users", policy => policy.RequireClaim("user_roles", "users"));
                options.AddPolicy(
                    "Admin",
                    policyBuilder => policyBuilder.RequireAssertion(
                        context => context.User.HasClaim(claim =>
                                   claim.Type == "admin" && (claim.Value == "contractor" || claim.Value == "users")
                    ))
                );
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // We check the cookie to confirm that we are authenticated
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // When we sign in we will deal out a cookie
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //Use this to check if we are alllowed to do something.
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
options.CallbackPath = "/Index";
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:oidc:Authority"];
                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:oidc:ClientId"];
                //options.ResponseType = useLoadTest ? "code id_token token" : "code id_token";
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = false;
                options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/protocol/openid-connect/logout";
                options.SignedOutRedirectUri = "Redirect-here";
                //options.SignedOutRedirectUri = callBackUrl.ToString();
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
            })
            .AddCookie(setup => setup.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60));
```

appsettings.json

```
"Authentication": {
    "oidc": {
      "Authority": "http:/keycloak-testing-ip/auth/realms/project",
      "ClientId": "demo"
    }
```

before login:
[image]

after login:
[image]

so what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly add the Json mapping for the 'role' claim key in the `AddOpenIdConnect` options:

`options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey("role", "role");`

If you omit this, the roles will not be populated from the claims that are passed by Keycloak.
You can easily check this by setting a breakpoint right after the oidc challenge (something like `await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("oidc", new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUri });`.
When this has returned you can check the roles for your user.

Comment: I've tried to add as you suggested, but still nothing changes

Comment: Did you try to debug and check which claims are populated after authentication?